# How to set parameters of function used in apply()?

Tags: r, apply

I want to do `boxplot.stats` on each attribute of `iris` data and I do not want to use `for` loop. So my code is:

```
apply(iris[, 1:4], 2, boxplot.stats)
```

It works good. However, I want to set the parameter `do.conf = F` of `boxplot.stat`.
I tried two ways :

```
apply(iris[, 1:4], 2, boxplot(x, do.conf = F))
```

and

```
apply(iris[, 1:4], 2, boxplot(do.conf = F))
```

They do not work. An error was returned:

```
**Error in boxplot(x, do.conf = F) : object 'x' not found**
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please use `lapply` when iterating over column of a data frame.  `apply` is for matrices

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it as an additional argument:

```
apply(iris[, 1:4], 2, boxplot.stats, do.conf = F)
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much!

Comment: Then pls accept, so the question closes. Thank you!